# Hovering over one div changes another's img

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover

I need to change an image of one div while hovering over another. So far i have this

```
$('#button').on({
    'hover': function(){
        $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', 'http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranas_zpsczoquizc.png');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0bxwokop/2/)

But it doesn't work..

EDIT While it works in fiddle, the solution does not work in my local file.

Comment: what is ekranasStatic. There is no DOM with this id in the demo jsfiddle

Comment: @Benas, Does my answer solved your confusion?

Comment: @Parag Bhayani it did, just need to figure out where to put 'mouseleave' now

Comment: @BenasLengvinas : it is same as mouseenter, see my updated answer

Comment: Ah yes. It worked. Just in jsfidlle however...In my local code it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hover is deperecated with latest versions of jQuery. it is divided into two  events mouseenter and mouserleave. use those event it will be helpful

> As of 1.9, the event name string "hover" is no longer supported as a
>   synonym for "mouseenter mouseleave". This allows applications to
>   attach and trigger a custom "hover" event. Changing existing code is a
>   simple find/replace, and the "hover" pseudo-event is also supported in
>   the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify migration. [Reference](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

```
$('#button').on({
    'mouseenter': function(){
        $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', 'http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranas_zpsczoquizc.png');
    }
});

$('#button').on({
    'mouseleave': function(){
        $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', 'http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/some_other.png');
    }
});
```

If you still want to use hover events then there is direct hover function provided by jQuery, with [reference](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', 'http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranas_zpsczoquizc.png');
  }, function() {
    // change to default on hover out
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to change it on mouseover and reset on mouseout. If you use `data-*` attribute it will be easier.

```js
$('#button').hover(function() {
  var img = $('#ekranasStatic').data('toggle-src');
  $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', img);
}, function() {
  var img = $('#ekranasStatic').data('original-src');
  $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', img);
});
```

```css
.img {
  /*** TURI BUT 850 PX **/
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 520px;
  top: 110px;
  z-index: 99;
}
#button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 296px;
  left: 1120px;
  background: url("http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/knopkes_zpsp3qr4xyn.png") no-repeat;
  z-index: 2200;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#button:hover {
  animation: knopke 0.1s steps(2);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
@keyframes knopke {
  to {
    background-position: -100px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#ekranasStatic {
  width: 735px;
  height: 602px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 375px;
  z-index: 10000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img" src="http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/galerija3_zpszlnkhebp.png">
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="ekranai">
  <img id="ekranasStatic" src="http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranasStatic_zpswrnrw7f8.png" data-original-src="http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranasStatic_zpswrnrw7f8.png" data-toggle-src="http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranas_zpsczoquizc.png"
  />
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0bxwokop/9/)

Comment: It works, however, as @Parag Bhayani solution this one only work in jsFiddle and not in my localhost. Maybe you know why is that?

Comment: Somehow it works in another html file...must be something wrong with this one

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$('#button').on({
    'hover': function(){
```

to :

```
  $('#button').hover({ function(){ });
```

Comment: `hover` is not an event. I don't think it can be used inside `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('#button').on('hover', function () {
        $('#ekranasStatic').attr('src', 'http://i1064.photobucket.com/albums/u378/Benas_Lengvinas/ekranas_zpsczoquizc.png');
    }
);
```

Js Fiddle [Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/0bxwokop/7/)